# how to check network availablity in mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an mobile application where I need to check if the device is connected to internet and if it is not connected then it should show an popup saying you are not connected to internet and it should have a option for settings on clicking which it should to take the settings of the mobile where the user can turn on the WIFI or mobile internet

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions:

1. > need to check if the device is connected to internet and if it is not
   >   connected then it should show an popup saying you are not connected to
   >   internet

   You can use the [WL.Device.getNetworkInfo](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Device.html?cp=SSHS8R_7.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-0&lang=en) API method, for example:

   ```
   function wlCommonInit() {
       WL.Device.getNetworkInfo(function (networkInfo) {
           if (networkInfo.isNetworkConnected) {
               alert ("connected");
           } else {
               alert ("not connected");
           }
       });
   }
   ```
2. > should have a option for settings on clicking which it should to take
   >   the settings of the mobile device where the user can turn on the WIFI or
   >   mobile internet

   This could probably be implemented using a Cordova plug-in. Find a Cordova plug-in that allows you to open the settings screen of the device or even deeper, the settings > network setting screen of the device, there the user could do it. However, I would simply tell the user to go there on his own and not implement that... your choice, more complicated.